# K - Size subset of array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Folks,

I tried the code for k-size subset of an array. It prints the array subset, but doesn't show up the pairs like [1,2] and [2,1].

Below is my code :-

```
class KSizeSubSetArray {

    private static void getSubsets(List<Integer> superSet, int k, int idx, Set<Integer> current,List<Set<Integer>> solution) {

            if (current.size() == k) {
                solution.add(new HashSet<Integer>(current));
                return;
            }

            if (idx == superSet.size()) 
                return;

            Integer x = superSet.get(idx);
            current.add(x);


            getSubsets(superSet, k, idx+1, current, solution);

            current.remove(x);

            getSubsets(superSet, k, idx+1, current, solution);
        }

        public static List<Set<Integer>> getSubsets(List<Integer> superSet, int k) {
            List<Set<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
            getSubsets(superSet, k, 0, new HashSet<Integer>(), res);
            return res;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                List<Integer> superSet = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                superSet.add(1);
                superSet.add(2);
                superSet.add(3);
                superSet.add(4);
                System.out.println(getSubsets(superSet,2));

        }
}
```

The above code prints the output :-

> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]

But I'm expecting to print both pairs like [1,2] and [2,1].

Am  I missing something ?

Comment: Note: by the definition of set, [1,2] = [2,1]

Comment: Without looking at the code, the set [1,2] is by definition the same as [2,1]. Or do you mean that the code should return also [2,1] no matter the definition?

Answer (score 1):

This code generates *sets*. The sets `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` are equal (a set doesn't have any order). Therefore, only `[1,2]` is present in the output.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> It [HashSet] makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

So it is coincidence that `[1, 2]` is printed. It could as well have been `[2, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

As we already have written, by definition the set [1,2] is the same with [2,1]. But if you look at the code in order to undersdant WHY this is correct, than you will note that 1 is added, and after that it is continued once with it, and one without it (when it is removed), but once got at 2, it never returns to the index 1.

Comment: The order of insertion is *not* the reason why `[1,2]` is in the output and `[2, 1]` is not. A set doesn't have any order.

Comment: Yes, that is not the reason, but what I am explaining is why the list of sets does not contains TWO sets with [1,2] (no matter how they are printed).